# Angular modules - best practises of reusing shared components from domain modules with lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ng-modules

I know the concepts of lazy loading and sharing modules, but I'm not sure what will be the best practice of deviding code into modules in my app. I have 4 pages:

1. Dashboard
2. Drinks
3. Drinks recipes
4. Bars

So I divided my app into 4 logical, domain modules: `DashboardModule`, `DrinksModule`, `RecipesModule`, `BarsModule`. While coding I've noticed that I have some dependencies between modules:

1. `DashboardModule` reuses some components from all other modules.
2. `BarsModule` and `RecipesModule` reuse some components from `DrinksModule`

So problems I see are:

1. With `DashboardModule` all other modules must be loaded, but only some components are used.
2. `DrinksModule` is always loaded, but only some components are used in other modules.

I don't want to move all of that reused components to a single `SharedModule` because these components fit the specific domain (like bar or drinks) and also some components will be loaded unnecessarily.

Is it sense to split these domain modules like `DrinksModule` and `SharedDrinksModule` and what will be the best project structure for that? Or maybe there is a better practice to handle these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to create a sharedModule and move the resuble components to that module. Also make sure to mske those component as dump component.

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution. Let's say I have DrinkPreviewComponent which is used in some DrinksModule component but also in dashboard. I'd like to have this component in DrinksModule/DrinksSharedModule because it meets the domain context. I think SharedModule should be rather for some generic components, helpers and utils.

Comment: If it is a dump component, you can put them in a shared module. Dump component in the sense it does not have any dependency. ou just need to pass the input and it will show the view depending on your input. For example star rating component, in that case, we just need to pass the count from 1 to 5 and it will show the starts depending on the count.